# How to change value of TemplateField dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, templatefield

I have a GridView and I want to refresh a row (not the whole grid) when it gets selected. I tried to change `Text` property for each of `GridView.SelectedRow.Cells` when Grid selected index changes. It seems to work for `DataField`, but not for `TemplateField`. For `TemplateField` I got strange results - the value for selected row changes properly, but when I select another row, the value of `TemplateField` for previously selected row becomes blank. Brief illustration :

```
1. Nothing selected
--------------------------
id          template_field
--------------------------
 1          value_1
 2          value_2

2. First record selected
--------------------------
id          template_field
--------------------------
 1          updated_value_1
 2          value_2

3. Second record selected
--------------------------
id          template_field
--------------------------
 1          [blank!]
 2          updated_value_2
```

Eventually, I end up with blank `template_field` for each record except selected. What is the proper way to change the text of TemplateField ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a TextBox control to your template, and change *it* instead of the cell contents.  You should be able to get at it via something like this:

```
TextBox tb = GridView.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Controls[0] as TextBox;
if(tb != null)
   tb.Text = newValue;
```

Comment: I'll try it. I've already tried changing `Text` of `Controls[0]`, but this property is read-only, so it didn't work.

Comment: But did you add a TextBox control to the template field?  So that you're trying to change the contents of a TextBox (which has its own viewstate, so should remember the changes).

Comment: I'm trying it now... Thanks for idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does work. By the way, it doesn't have to be a TextBox, it works fine with Label as well (I don't need it to be editable).